# Timing of programs in Windows

Tags: windows, performance, measurement, time

Is there a Windows equivalent of the time Unix command?

time measures the time spent by a process in both user and kernel lands.

```
$ time for i in `seq 100`; do echo -n HI; done
HIHIHIHIHIHIHIHIHIHIHIHIHIHIHIHIHIHIHIHIHIHIHIHIHIHIHI<... snip ...>
real    0m0.005s
user    0m0.000s
sys     0m0.004s
```

The idea is for the script/program/command to be programmable/automatable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is timeit.exe in the [2k3 Resource Kit](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=9D467A69-57FF-4AE7-96EE-B18C4790CFFD&displaylang=en) which looks good enough for my purposes.

(was missing "unix" from the Google search term)

Answer (score 2):

Powershell's `Measure-Command` will measure the amount of time a command takes to run.

Usage:
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd347702.aspx